# How do I include a table in another table's cell in Microsoft Report viewer

Tags: report-viewer2010

I am working on a project which includes creating some reports and I am using Microsoft Report Viewer for this.

Let's say I have Table 1 and I need to put another table let's say Table 2 into a cell of Table 1, when I drag Table 2 into Table 1's referred cell I get the below error

**The tablix ‘Tablix1’ has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members.**

How can I achieve this? Is it something about parent groups or child groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a table, add a parent group(rest is another solution) add a child and add a table into the cell